# Can't cast char array into int value in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

I am making a caesar cipher and am trying to convert the char value of each letter into an int so the shift value can change it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < plainTextInput.Length; ++i)
{
   chars[i] = ((int)chars[i]) + shiftAmount;         
}
```

It says it cannot convert int into char. How do i fix this problem?

Comment: It seems like chars[] is an array of chars.  If so, you need to cast it back to a char: chars[i]=(char)((int)chars[i])+shiftAmount;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly cast it back:

```
for (int i = 0; i < plainTextInput.Length; ++i)
{
   chars[i] = (char)(((int)chars[i]) + shiftAmount);         
}
```

However, you're going to run into trouble pretty quickly once you shift past `z`.

Answer (score 0):

By explicitly casting:

```
chars[i] = (char)(((int)chars[i]) + shiftAmount);
```

I'd rewrite your loop:

```
var enciphered = chars.Select(c => (char)((int)c + shiftAmount)).ToArray();
```

What are you planning to do if you shift to a non-printable character? Standard Caesar cipher wraps around. You should incorporate that.

Answer (score 0):

When I compile that code, I get the following error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Why yes, you *are* missing a cast:

```
chars[i] = (char)(((int)chars[i]) + shiftAmount);
```